# Adapter's getView called multiple times for same positions, how to know what view will appear on the screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, adapter

I know the reason why the getView method of an Adapter is called more than once, but is there a way for knowing which of the returned view will be actually displayed on the activity?

Until now I put all the returned view linked to the same position in a list and, every time I need to modify a shown view I modify all the views corresponding to that position (one of those will be the right one...).
Surely is not the best way...

Here a piece of code of my adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Vector<ImageView> vectorView[] = new Vector<ImageView>[25];
    public MyAdapter(Activity context) {
        ...
    }

    public doSomeStuffOnAView(int position) {
        // needs to know which view corresponds to the given position
        // in order to avoid the following for cycle
        for (ImageView iv: vector[position]) {
            // do something
        }

    }

    public View getView(int position, ...) {
        ImageView childView = ...;
        if (vector[position]==null) {
            vector[position]=new Vector<ImageView>();
        }
        vector[position].add(childView);
        return childView;
    }
}
```

The method `getView(...)` might be called more than once for each position, but just one returned view per position will be shown on the activity. I need to know which of these. I thought it was the one returned the last time getView has been called for a position, but it is now always true.

Answer (score 0):

one way but it is not standard.. you can directly check with integer variable i.e. hardcoded type. You have list of views in your xml file. jst cross check & compare with integer variable.